# Jupyter Notebook: Get class file path when initializing an object of that class

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been working with **Jupyter Notebook** for the past months but only now I started working with classes and custom modules.

I have a class named `Class` (Class.ipynb file) which I use to instantiate an object `class_object` from a different jupyter file (Object.ipynb).

I was wondering how could I return the Class.ipynb file absolute path when class_object is initiated (ie in the **init** method). I can't seem to get the **file** method as in a regular python class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple solution did the trick. I was trying everything inside init() method but the solution was a static variable.

```
class Class:
    class_file=sys.path[0]
    def __init__(self):
        print(class_file)
```